# Flutter future.then() returns empty string

Tags: flutter, dart, future

The following code print the right string.

```
String genreString = '';
for (var genreID in list["genre_ids"]) {
     DBProvider.db.getGenreName(genreID).then((value) {
          genreString = genreString + value + ", ";
          print(genreString);
     });
}
```

But I want to acess "genreString" outside the for loop. When I want to print it like this.

```
String genreString = '';
for (var genreID in list["genre_ids"]) {
     DBProvider.db.getGenreName(genreID).then((value) {
          genreString = genreString + value + ", ";
     });
}
print(genreString);
```

it would not work. I also try "return" but it does not change.

May someone have a solution

Comment: Please read: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: `final genreNames = await Future.wait(list["genre_ids"].map(DBProvider.db.getGenreName))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Note that the function containing this code has to be `async`.

```
String genreString = '';
for (var genreID in list["genre_ids"]) {
     final value = await DBProvider.db.getGenreName(genreID);
     genreString = genreString + value + ", ";
}
print(genreString);
```